# How to format search autocompletion part lists?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm currently working on an AppEngine project, and I'd like to implement autocompletion of search terms. The *items* that can be searched for are reasonably unambiguous and short, so I was thinking of implementing it by giving each *item* a list of incomplete typings. So `foobar` would get a list like `[f, fo, foo, foob, fooba, foobar]`. The user's text in the searchbox is then compared to this list, and positive matches are suggested.

There are a couple of possible optimizations in this list that I was thinking of:

- Removing spaces punctuation from search terms. `Foo. Bar` to `FooBar`.
- Removing capital letters
- Removing leading particles like "the", "a", "an". `The Guy` would be `guy`, and indexed as `[g, gu, guy]`.
- Only adding substring longer than  2 or 3 to the indexing list. So `The Guy` would be indexed as `[gu, guy]`. I thought that suggestions that only match the first letter would not be so relevant.

The users search term would also be formatted in this way, after which the DB is searched. Upon suggesting a search term, the particles, punctuation, and capital letters would be added according to the suggested object's full name. So searching for "the" would give no suggestions, but searching for "The Gu.." or "gu" would suggest "The Guy".

Is this a good idea? Mainly: would this formatting help, or only cause trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already run into the same problem and the solution that I adopted was very similar to your idea. I split the items into words, convert them to lowercase, remove accents, and create a list of startings. For instance, `"Báz Bar"` would become `['b', 'ba', 'bar', 'baz']`.

I have posted the code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078738/gae-simple-searching-autocomplete/2078830#2078830). The search box [of this site](http://www.toape.com.br) is using it. Feel free to use it if you like.

Comment: Is it useful to split the words on spaces? How do you match the string when the user types _both_ words in the searchbox? Do you need to make a separate DB query for each word? Like `word1 in startings + word2 in startings + word3 etc...`

Comment: No, actually you can just cascade one filter for each word:  `query.filter('start' = 'word1').filter('start = ', 'word2') .... `